# For Win 8 Metro App, how to start background task immediately without Trigger?

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

The MSDN [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Task-Sample-9209ade9) showed how to use the built-in System Triggers to start background tasks. How do you start a task without Trigger? Or how do you implement a custom Trigger? Some code would be nice.

I am using XAML/C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/97b728ef-1541-4561-829c-7a5b9bd491d2). Seems that you can't just launch a Background Task or make your own Trigger. In this case, a Metro app may not be appropriate...

Comment: In that thread there is a link to a good read for background tasks [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27411). Background tasks can quickly overwhelm the types of low-power SoCs that Win8 is designed to run on. Their use is restricted to ensure that developers do not ruin the end user's experience by unnecessarily draining battery or slowing down the hardware.