# How can I start a Windows App Background Task immediately after registering it?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, .net-4.5, windows-store-apps, c#-5.0

I am writing a Metro App that will only run on PCs (so there is no, or at least less, worry about the battery life).  I need it to register and run a background task when the user clicks a button.  It registers fine, but I have found no way to make it run sooner than at a 15 minute delay, which is useless for this app.  Any ideas how I can get it to run immediately?

Also I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859139/for-win-8-metro-app-how-to-start-background-task-immediately-without-trigger) that says its not possible, but someone must have figured out a way.

***Edit:***

My reasoning for requiring this task is such:

My app will be reading and writing files as they appear over an extended period of time, anywhere from a few minutes to several hours.  During the majority this time, it is unlikely that the app will be presented in the foreground.  Because I need the code to be able to continue executing, it seemed the best way was to create a background task, but I can find no way to manually initiate this task outside of Visual Studio, though in Visual Studio it works perfectly.  If there is a more appropriate way to handle this execution, I am willing to use it.

Comment: What have you tried exactly?  The answer to the linked question is pretty clear why this still isn't possible. All Windows Store Applications have the same restrictions no matter if they are published or unpublished on the Store itself. Why don't you just trigger it right away?

Comment: @Ramhound How can I trigger right away? I don't see a way to do it with the severely limited triggers provided by Microsoft.

Comment: One possible way is to trigger it against the `InternetAvailable` at the end of the day it sounds like you should just do a traditional non-WinRT desktop application. The 15 minute timer is only to prevent to many updates while the system is locked. You should be able to trigger it while the system is unlocked before that time.

Comment: @Ramhound I was under the impression that the `internetAvailable` trigger only fired when the network status switched from unavailable to available (i.e. it would not fire if internet was already available before registering).

Comment: Have you tried?  The documentation doesn't indicate that.

Comment: @Ramhound I have just tried, and yes it waits until you have been disconnected and the reconnect to the internet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**

Revision due to the extra information from OP.

The only way I can think you could do this via a metro app is to ask your user to "snap" your app against the desktop - on your snapped app they can hit start/stop and carry only using the desktop at the same time with both apps running in the foreground.

---

I think my other answer is not complete so I will try to offer a better answer.

To clarify: you state that your whole reason for using a background task is so your app will continue running some code even if your app is suspended.

**Background Tasks:**

You cannot trigger a WinRT background task to run immediately.

Bear in mind that a background task by default has 1 second of CPU every 2 hours and there's no way of specifying when it will activate - you can only use opportunistic triggering - no good to you in this case.

Further, even if your app is made a lock-screen application, you cannot specify the immediate processing of a background task unless you are using push notifications, which aren't appropriate for what you are trying to do. For a lock-screen app you'd generally get 2 seconds of CPU every 15 minutes.

**OnSuspending:**

However, if your app is being suspended you still have a few seconds (5, according to this: http://www.redlist.ch/post/Time-limit-on-suspending-a-WinRT-app.aspx) of time to tidy up before your app is suspended by the OS. This suspension-grace-time is longer than the time you would have in the background task anyway!

Therefore, I would suggest not using background tasks and instead to initiate a background thread (as per my other answer) to do your button-press action (using local state to record its progress). Now, if you also hook into the App onsuspending event, you can use this to see if something hasn't been completed from a button-press action and complete it.

Hope it makes sense. Good luck!

Comment: That may be the answer I am looking for, but I am not familiar with background threading.  I have modified my question to explain my purpose.  Do you still believe a background thread will work for my intentions?

Comment: Not 100% sure of your requirements but it seems like you'll need a combination (and communication between) your UI and background tasks so you can process your files in a timely manner. I highly recommend to read and re-read the Introduction to BG Tasks from MS - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27411  good luck!

Comment: The only thing relayed between my UI and the background is a start and stop command.  My requirements are basically to start a long running method that will continue execution even if the app is suspended.

Comment: Given the nature of my app, the likely use case is this: launch the app, press the start button, immediately switch to the desktop, return to my app only when ready to stop.  Thus, that is not an ideal solution for my situation.

Comment: Ah, ok I see what you're doing now. Sounds like a desktop app solution would be much easier! (which you can still put on the app store). Maybe do all your CPU/I-O work on a desktop app - get it to write what it does to a shared DB and use a metro app to report from that DB.

Comment: or make your app run in snapped mode with the desktop - see update

Comment: That (snapped mode) is a good idea.  I had not considered that for some reason.  I will try it out now.

Answer (score 6):

The way I got around this was to create a common function that can be called from both the application and the background task.

In your case when the user clicks the register button, you can register the task, and then call the common function (from your app).  When the task runs, it can also call the same common function.

Comment: That is a very good idea.  Unfortunately my task is designed to be long running and thus only run once, so that won't work.

Comment: Tasks in Windows 8 cannot be long running. Your use case is not valid for the reality. You only have 1 CPU second per 2 hours.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT - In my defense, the question (when I answered it) did not mention that the task was long running.  My answer works if the task time is short.

Comment: @chuex, dude, don't sweat it. I didn't judge.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the task based on a UI action (button press) you may as well hook into the button press event and kick off your task in a new thread in the UI process. 
e.g.

```
new TaskFactory().StartNew(() => YourBackgroundTaskMethod())
```

You won't block the UI and you can easily marshall results back from the background thread to the UI if you need to.

This way you don't have to rely on your app being promoted to a lock screen app - which is a requirement if you want to run background timer tasks.

Comment: If I use that to start my background task method, will it continue running if my app is suspended? (That is the whole reason I am using a background task)

Comment: No but you can pass a cancellation token if your app is being suspended. I've done this before to allow a tidy-up. When you say a long-running task, you only have 2 seconds of CPU to use, even if it's a "one-shot" timer task. I'd recommend putting a rest web service in the cloud and using your background task to call that to do its processing.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear, I need it to continue running, even if the app is suspended.  Also, it is doing local file manipulation, so a remote processor will not work.

Comment: I don't think you can do it :( 1. You are user-reliant on being able to run timer tasks. 2. You will not be able to dictate exactly when it is triggered anyway. 3. You will not be able to execute a long-running task as they are massively resource-constrained in cpu time and network /io usage

Comment: 1. I would prefer not to run it on a timer, I want it to execute immediately when the button is pressed. 2. That is the purpose of this question. 3. I have done excessive work to minimize the resources used by this task, and it is currently next to nothing.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your use-case would best benefit from a notification system. You could send notifications to your application when you create the files (either from the file creating service or a desktop-side .Net 4.5 application that communicates to your application via a cloud service).

Regarding background work in general, you MAY schedule tile notifications to change every minute with [Windows.UI.Notifications.ScheduledTileNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.scheduledtilenotification.scheduledtilenotification).

Answer (score 0):

you can subscribe to raw push notification event. when you want to start the process you can request your server to send a raw notification, which will activate your background task.